# Возможно ли создание функции оптимизирующее получение элементов по id?

Tags: javascript, html, inner

Доброго дня всем, вопрос такой:

Имею в html файле множество значений `input` и `span`. Возможно ли создать функцию которая при передаче туда `id` элемента будет выдавать содержащееся в `input` или `span` значение и изменять его?

Пробовал такое но это не работает, вопрос почему?

```js
function st(x) {
  var y = document.getElementById(x);
  y.innerHTML = "99";
}
```

```html
<input id=something onchange="st(this.id);">
```

Может вопрос тупой, не судите строго, я новичок, заранее ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО. ))

Comment: у элемента `input` значение устанавливается присваиванием свойству `value`: `y.value = "99";`

Comment: Если смотреть в DOM, можно убедиться, что всё работает. 99 на месте.

Comment: Igor огромное спасибо, ошибка была очень глупая, теперь всё работает, спасибо )

Comment: Эм, как теперь удалить этот позорный  вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Поле внутри `input` - задается атрибутом `value`:

```
<input value="...value...">
```

```js
function st(x) {
  var y = document.getElementById(x);
  y.value = "99";
}
```

```html
<input id=something onchange="st(this.id);">
```

С помощью `innerHTML` можно задать текст внутри тега, между закрывающим и открывающим тегом:

```
<div>...innerHTML...</div>
<span>...innerHTML...</span>
```

```js
function st(x) {
  var y = document.getElementById(x);
  y.innerHTML = "99";
}
```

```html
<div id=something onClick="st(this.id);">Нажмите здесь</div>
```